# High level Kafka Consumer Only Consumes Half Of Messages Sent By Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have implemented a high level consumer per the example page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

When the code runs, it only consume half of the messages produced.  I have a basic 3 node zookeeper cluster and 2 kafka brokers.  When I run the simple consumer code (not high level consumer), all the messages are consumed.  Any ideas will be appreciated.

Consumer code

```
   public void run() {
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put("test", 2);
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get("test");

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        int threadNumber = 0;

        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {

            executor.submit(new Consumer(stream, threadNumber));
            threadNumber++;
        }
    }

    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "zookeeper01:2181,zookeeper02:2181,zookeeper03:2181");
        props.put("group.id", "Consumers");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "10000");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "1000");
        props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "500");

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);
    }
```

Comment: How many partition are there in the topic "test". Could there be another consumer using the group.id "Consumers"?. If you change the group.id to be something else and rerun do you get all of the messages?

Comment: 4 partitions.  There are no other consumers.

Comment: what is the version of kafka ?

Comment: brokers are consumers are kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.